# How to rotate vertical video for DVD

Tags: video-conversion, dvd-burning, video-playback

I have a video recorded in vertical format and I want to put it on a disc but it keeps turning the video sideways so it'll be horizontal. Any way to make it play vertical? I'm using Daemon Tools Lite now but if you know a software that allows you to burn vertical videos that's free, please suggest it.

Comment: As a minimum you'd need to say what program you are using to create the DVD

Comment: @Mokubai okay I'll edit it

Comment: A DVD can't play "vertical video".  What you actually want to do is edit the video so that it's rotated and pillarboxed (black margins on the left and right), then you can burn it with Daemon Tools or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Movie Maker 2012 can edit a video so that it's rotated.  [It's free](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14220/windows-movie-maker-download) and available for Windows 7/8/8.1 as part of Windows Essentials.

[image: Screenshot]